# Save a factory after build, with RSpec, FactoryGirl and Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have an Account model with has_secure_password (that automagically creates 2 attr_accessors: password and password_confirmation, required on create). I'd like to avoid to specify those fields when I update an account object, so I'm trying to create a test with RSpec and factoryGirl like this:

```
describe Account do
    before do
        @account = FactoryGirl.build(:account) # this does not save the object
    end

    describe "password is not present (on update)" do
        before do
            @account.save
            @account.name = 'updated without specifying the password field'
        end
        it "should be valid" do
            should be_valid
        end
    end
end
```

But, I end up with the error:

```
   Account password is not present (on update) should be valid
      Failure/Error: should be_valid
        expected valid? to return true, got false
      # ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I cannot use the FactoryGirl.create(:account) because the before block gets executed before many other tests and the model validates the uniqueness of the email field.

---

If I use FactoryGirl.create(:account) within the initial before block (I'm now using a sequence generator to create a unique email address)... this test fails:

```
describe "email is already taken" do
    before do
      same_user = @account.dup
      same_user.email = @account.email.upcase # let's test against case sensitive strings
      same_user.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

These are some validations inside the Account model:

```
 validates :name, :surname, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                    format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i }
  validates :birthday, presence: true

  # Password validations
  validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 20 }, allow_blank: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :unless => lambda { self.password.blank? }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a sequence generator to generate a unique email for each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will generate a unique email address every time you use factory to create/build an account

```
sequence(:unique_email) {|n| "email#{n}@example.com" }
factory :account do
  email { generate(:unique_email) }
end
```

You don't have to save the object to check for validity

```
describe "email is already taken" do
    before do
      same_user = @account.dup
      same_user.email = @account.email.upcase # let's test against case sensitive strings
      same_user.valid?
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

Comment: I've added your code, thank you. But now I have another problem: take a look at the initial post. ;)

Comment: updated the answer. object.valid? populates the error on object. I don't know if rspec calls the valid? method internally or if it just checks the error attribute. If it calls the valid? method, you can remove the last line from before block

Comment: I did have to modify the should_not statement with same_user.should_not to make it work. Finally, the test pass!